# Why XMLReader repeat mysql insert function inside while and can't stop?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, while-loop, xmlreader

I am using XMLReader to import huge xml file by elements to MySQL database. Xml contains 1 547 772 tags (element) named 'RECORD'.

XML example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RECORD><NAME>ДОШКІЛЬНИЙ НАВЧАЛЬНИЙ ЗАКЛАД №1 ЗАГАЛЬНОГО РОЗВИТКУ УЖГОРОДСЬКОЇ МІСЬКОЇ РАДИ ЗАКАРПАТСЬКОЇ ОБЛАСТІ</NAME><SHORT_NAME>ДНЗ №1</SHORT_NAME><EDRPOU>34888585</EDRPOU><ADDRESS>88000, Закарпатська обл., місто Ужгород, ВУЛИЦЯ М.ВОВЧКА, будинок 47,  "А"</ADDRESS><BOSS>НАКОНЕЧНА ОЛЕНА АНАТОЛІЇВНА</BOSS><KVED>85.10 Дошкільна освіта</KVED><STAN>зареєстровано</STAN><FOUNDERS><FOUNDER>УПРАВЛІННЯ ОСВІТИ УЖГОРОДСЬКОЇ МІСЬКОЇ РАДИ, розмір внеску до статутного фонду - 0.00 грн.</FOUNDER>...</FOUNDERS></RECORD>...
```

For MySQL connection use

```
function connectBase(){

    include __DIR__ . '/../../settings/sql.set.php';
    $mysql = mysqli_connect($_sqlhost, $_sqluser, $_sqlpass, $_sqldb);
    mysqli_query($mysql, "Set charset utf8");
    mysqli_query($mysql, "Set character_set_client = utf8");
    mysqli_query($mysql, "Set character_set_connection = utf8");
    mysqli_query($mysql, "Set character_set_results = utf8");
    mysqli_query($mysql, "Set collation_connection = utf8_general_ci");
    return $mysql;
}
```

Main function for parsing

```
function XMLReaderToDB($setting = false)
{

    $mysql = connectBase();
    $dir = __DIR__ . '/../../tmp/';
    $xmlURL = $dir . $setting['file'];
    $xml = new XMLReader();
    $xml->open($xmlURL);

    $start_time = time();
    $start = $setting['start'];
    $limit = $setting['limit'];
    $stop = $start + $limit;

    $i = 0;
    $count = 0;
    $result = 1;

    while($xml->read())
    {
            if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == $setting['tag']) {

                $item[] = "('items', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql, $xml->readOuterXML()) . "')";
            }

            if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $xml->name == $setting['tag']) {
                $i++;
                $count++;
                if ($count >= 500) {
                    insertXMLtoDB($mysql, $item);
                    $item = array();
                    $count = 0;
                }
            }
        if($i == $stop){
            break;
        }
    }
    $xml->close();
    insertXMLtoDB($mysql, $item);

    $mysql->close();

    $end_time = time();
    $time_elapsed_secs = $end_time - $start_time;
    echo '<br/>Items: ' . $i . '<br/>';
    echo 'Start: ' . date('H:i:s', $start_time) . '<br/>';
    echo 'End: ' . date('H:i:s', $end_time) . '<br/>';
    echo $time_elapsed_secs . ' sec. (' . ($time_elapsed_secs /60) . ' min.)';
    die;
}
```

And for MySQL insert

```
function insertXMLtoDB($mysql, $data = false){
    mysqli_query($mysql,"INSERT INTO _parse_tmp (parse_key, parse_value) VALUES " . implode(", ", $data));
    $data = array();
    // echo 'Success';
}
```

But, MySQL requests don't stop after 1 547 772 inserts and "while" continues to run. I notice if uncommenting echo 'Success'; in insertXMLtoDB function, "while" is stopping at 1 547 772 inserts and finishing correctly.
What is wrong in my functions?

Comment: Do you mean the second call to `insertXMLtoDB($mysql, $item);`, which is after the while loop has finished is being called to write the last chunk of data.  This will virtually always have something to write as you only write every 500 records.

Comment: Exactly. But insertXMLtoDB($mysql, $item); after 'while' work fine. Removing whis nubction not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've never personally used XMLReader however, I'd assume you could try to add another condition to your statement such as `while($xml->read() && $i != $stop)` opposed to having it within your loop directly. Ah also just noticed after your usage of the function `insertXMLtoDB` you re-declare `$data` although you'll notice you set it to NULL every time your call the function, therefore setting it to an array is pointless.

Comment: I tried to replace by 'while($xml->read() && $i != $stop)' and set '$stop = 1600000', but got same result, "while" don't stop.

Comment: And you're sure that it has completed the insertion of all of the data?

Comment: When the value of $i reached to 1600000, the function should stop. I am monitoring DB. At the base is added in groups of 500 items, but after adding 1600000 'while' does not stop and continues to add new elements (repeats).

Comment: while($xml->read() && $i != $stop) works fine if $i = 5000 (for example), but not work for big values like 1000000, 1500000 etc. And 'while' don't stop when 'RECORD' items (tags) in xml are over/

Comment: That's quite strange, I'm guessing you altered the maximum execution time limit?

Comment: Yes of course. But this script can not be executed without increasing the execution time limit.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why the script doesn't work fine. That's why I decided to change it.

```
function XMLReaderToDB($setting = false)
{
    $mysql = connectBase();

    $dir = __DIR__ . '/../../tmp/';
    $xmlURL = $dir . $setting['file'];
    $xml = new XMLReader();
    $xml->open($xmlURL);

    $start_time = time();
    $start = $setting['start'];
    $limit = $setting['limit'];
    $stop = $start + $limit;

    $i = 0;
    $count = 0;
    while (($valid = $xml->read()) && $xml->name !== $setting['tag']) ;
    while ($valid) {
        $i++;
        $count++;
        $item[] = "('" . $setting['type'] . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql, $xml->readOuterXML()) . "')";
        if ($count == 500) {
            insertXMLtoDB($mysql, $item);
            $item = array();
            $count = 0;
        }
        $valid = $xml->next($setting['tag']);
    }
    $xml->close();
    insertXMLtoDB($mysql, $item);
    $mysql->close();

    $end_time = time();
    $time_elapsed_secs = $end_time - $start_time;
    echo '<br/>Items: ' . $i . '<br/>';
    echo 'Start: ' . date('H:i:s', $start_time) . '<br/>';
    echo 'End: ' . date('H:i:s', $end_time) . '<br/>';
    echo $time_elapsed_secs . ' sec. (' . ($time_elapsed_secs /60) . ' min.)';
    return;
}
```